# How to iterate over a PriorityQueue?

Tags: java, collections, loops, priority-queue

```
for (Event e : pq)
```

doesn't iterate in the priority order.

```
while(!pq.isEmpty()){
  Event e = pq.poll();
}
```

This works but empties the queue.

Comment: How does that empty the queue? `peek()` doesn't remove elements.

Comment: `peek()` shouldnt remove the object

Comment: peek() continues on returning the head though

Comment: The logic in your while loop does not make sense. isEmpty is not like hasNext.

Comment: Had similar issue. Fixed using delegation and wrapper concept https://stackoverflow.com/a/51968633/1465553

Answer (score 42, accepted):

From the [Javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html)

> The Iterator provided in method `iterator()` is not guaranteed to traverse the elements of the PriorityQueue in any particular order. If you need ordered traversal, consider using `Arrays.sort(pq.toArray())`.

There are probably other equivalent mechanisms.

Comment: This answer would benefit from an example. `Arrays.sort(pq.toArray())` does nothing as far as I am aware off. First an array has to be created that holds the elements of the `PriorityQueue` then one can sort that array using `Arrays.sort(theActualArray, pq.comparer())`.

Comment: @Madmenyo 1. This answer does have an example. 2. `Arrays.sort()` does not do nothing. 3. There is no such method as `PriorityQueue.comparer()`.

Comment: This use is however extremely computationally intense. For the academic purposes id like to add that the time taken to iterate over sorted priority using this is n * n * log(n); where first N is time to iterate over the queue and N * log(N) is for sorting.

Comment: @LanVukušič no it's not. `pq.toArray()` takes O(n) (it simply copies the underlying array of the heap) and **then** sorting is O(n log(n)). Together it gives O(n + n log n) = O(n log n)

Comment: I found the same description in the Java doc without any executable example

Answer (score 44):

You can't traverse a `Priority Queue` in that order because of the underlying implementation (I think it's min-heap in Java).

**It's not a sorted array,** so that you can just go from one element to the one with the lesser priority.

Peeking (read the top element heap in the heap) is constant time `O(1)` because it looks at the smallest element.

To get the second next one you *must* dequeue the smallest top element, that's how it works.
Dequeing (re-heapify = `O(log n)` time) isn't just a matter of taking that element out, the underlying structure rearranges itself in order to bring the element with the least priority first.

Also, to go through the entire priority queue to read all items in the sorted order, it is an `O(n log(n))` operation.
So you may as well just grab all the elements in the queue and sort them (also `O(n log (n))` )and then you can go through them as you wish. The only disadvantage is that you're holding an extra-copy of the queue.

Nonetheless, if you need to traverse the data in this way a priority queue may not be the right data structure for your needs.

Comment: So `PriorityQueue` is pretty much useless, then?

Comment: Not at all, it is incredibly useful and very well optimised for what it's actually meant to do. It's faster to create than a fully sorted data structure (linear vs O(n log n)), but you can still find the min/max in constant time and enqueue/dequeue in log n. It's simply not the right data structure if you need to iterate in sorted order over all the elements.

Comment: Fair, though I'd go as far as to say it has pretty limited/specific uses.

Comment: @Qix not always iteration is a bad design; OP wanted to iterate over all elements, but I sometimes need to find the first element from the priority queue that matches some predicate. Then, sorting 10k array to get one of first 10 elements is pretty inefficient (esp. when done in a loop)

Answer (score 14):

A heap based priority queue only guarantees that the first element is the highest/lowest. There is no cheap (i.e. O(n)) way to get the elements in sorted form.

If you need to do this often, consider using a structure that maintains the elements in sorted form. For example, use `java.util.TreeSet`, and use either [`pollFirst()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/NavigableSet.html#pollFirst%28%29) or `pollLast()` in place of `peek()` / `poll()`

Answer (score 6):

Previous posters said everything but noone gave full working example (other than copying pq), so here it is:

```
Event[] events = pq.toArray(new Event[pq.size()]);
Arrays.sort(events, pq.comparator());
for (Event e : events) {
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make a copy of the queue and poll in a loop, in this example pq is the original priority queue:

```
PriorityQueue<Your_class> pqCopy = new PriorityQueue<Your_class>(pq);
while(!pqCopy.isEmpty()){
    Your_Class obj = pqCopy.poll();
    // obj is the next ordered item in the queue
    .....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Recently, I had same problem. I wanted to use some particular object from the priority queue and then keep remaining elements preserved.

1) I created a newPriorityQueue.
2) Used Iterator to parse every element in oldQueue
3) used oldQueue.poll() method to retrieve the element
4) insert the element 3) to newPriorityQueue if not used.

```
 Queue<String> newQueue = new PriorityQueue<String>(); 
    // Assuming that oldQueue have some data in it.

    Iterator<String> itr = oldQueue.iterator();
    while(itr.hasNext()){
        String str = oldQueue.poll();
        // do some processing with str
        if(strNotUsed){
            newQueue.offer(str);
        }
    }
```

In the end, oldQueue will be empty.
@ Others : - please suggest a better way if I can do the same thing. I can not use the iterator as it does not return elements in the correct order.

Answer (score 0):

So taking the priorityQueue in a List and then sorting it is a good option as mentioned above. Here are some details why the iterator gives unexpected results:

The iterator does not return elements in the correct order because it prints from the underlying data structure (similar to ArrayList). The ArrayList has data stored in it in the same way the data is stored in an Array implementation of BinaryHeap. For example:

```
PriorityQueue<Integer> pq = new PriorityQueue<>();
ArrayList<Integer> test = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(6,12,7,9,2));
test.forEach(x -> pq.add(x)); 
System.out.println("Priority Queue:- "+pq); [2, 6, 7, 12, 9]
```

where childOf(i) is 2*i+1 and 2*i+2 and parentOf(i) is (i-1)/2

Answer (score -1):

Inspiried by the idea from [@carlos-cuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41349854/590437), its actually very easy to construct a sorted iterator without consuming the orignal PriorityQueue. E.g. we can express this as an extension function in kotlin:

```kotlin
fun <E> PriorityQueue<E>.sortedIterator() = sequence {
    val pqCopy = PriorityQueue(this@sortedIterator)

    while(pqCopy.isNotEmpty()) yield(pqCopy.poll())
}

somePQ.sortedIterator().next() // ...
```

The key to success is copying the priority-queue with the built-in copy-constructor before polling from it.

I believe this is also more efficient than most of the other provided solutions in situtations where not just the complete iterator is being consumed.

Answer (score -2):

The `peek()` method does not remove anything from the queue, but because of this, it will continually get the top value until it IS empty.
I'm guessing you checked if it was empty after your while loop, which would give you this conclusion.

The only way to do this is to sort it yourself.
You can get the original comparator for it like this:

```
Event[] events = Arrays.sort(pq.toArray(), pq.comparator());
for (Event e : events) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: This is the same as the OP's original example.

Comment: I've since learned that this example isn't the best route.  Using a `comparator`, one does not need to convert the queue to an array.  `for (Event e : pq) {` should do the job.

Comment: Does `Arrays.sort` return thing? I think it returns `void`. I got error: `Found void, expect ....`.

Comment: It's certainly *not* the only way. He could create another PQ for example.

Answer (score -3):

```
for (Event event: pq.toArray(new Event[pq.size()])) {
    event.toString();
}
```

Comment: Please edit your answer to include some explanation. Code-only answers do very little to educate future SO readers. Your answer is in the moderation queue for being low-quality.

Comment: Your code does not solve the problem. Array should be sorted before iteration.