# Sort based on enum has a random behavior

Tags: java, sorting, enums, comparable

For the below code, I'm trying to sort a bean based on enum type. The enum type could also be null for this bean.

Sequence after sorting should be:

```
A -> B -> C -> null.
```

After running below code, elements are sorted like:

```
[A, A, C, B, B, null, C, null]
```

Please help

```
public class Bean implements Comparable<Bean> {

    enum Type {
      A, B, C
    }

    private Type type;
    private int i;
    private int j;

    public Bean(Type type, int i, int j) {
      this.type = type;
      this.i = i;
      this.j = j;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Bean that) {
       if (this.type == that.type) {
         return 0;
       }
       if (this.type != null && that.type != null) {
         if (this.type == type.A &&
            that.type == type.B) {
          return -1;
        }
        if (this.type == type.B &&
            that.type == type.C) {
          return -1;
        }
        if (this.type == type.A &&
            that.type == type.C) {
          return -1;
        }
        return 1;
      }

      return this.type == null ? 1 : -1;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
      return "Bean{" + "type=" + (type != null ? type : "Unknown") + "}";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
      Bean b1 = new Bean(Type.B, 1, 1);
      Bean b3 = new Bean(null, 3, 3);
      Bean b2 = new Bean(Type.C, 2, 2);
      Bean b0 = new Bean(Type.A, 0, 0);
      Bean b4 = new Bean(Type.B, 4, 4);
      Bean b5 = new Bean(null, 5, 5);
      Bean b6 = new Bean(Type.C, 6, 6);
      Bean b7 = new Bean(Type.A, 7, 7);

      List<Bean> list = new ArrayList<>();
      list.add(b1);
      list.add(b3);
      list.add(b2);
      list.add(b0);
      list.add(b4);
      list.add(b5);
      list.add(b6);
      list.add(b7);

      System.out.println(list);

      System.out.println(new PriorityQueue<Bean>(list));
    }
}
```

Comment: What's your objection to using the `ordinal()` method on a `java.lang.Enum`?

Comment: @Bathsheba *"What's your objection to using the ordinal() method on a java.lang.Enum?"* bad coding style? `compareTo()` is the much better alternative.

Comment: @TimothyTruckle; indeed but the *implementation* of `compareTo` can use `ordinal()`. The current way hardly scales.

Comment: @Bathsheba *"What's your objection to using the ordinal() method on a java.lang.Enum?"* it most likely will. But it is of no interest since we better use the `Comparable` interface provided by any *enum*

Comment: @TimothyTruckle: That does seem to be the case yes. Feel free to put as an answer: I'll upvote it.

Comment: @Bathsheba afaik, we should not use ordinal method. what if enum values are rearranged

Answer (score 4):

Instead f breaking yourself the neck nullifying enums you should do:

```
enum Type {
    A, B, C, INVALID
}
```

and then

```
public Bean(Type type, int i, int j) {
    this.type = type == null ? Type.INVALID : type;
    this.i = i;
    this.j = j;
}
```

and comparator will be as simple and easy to read as:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Bean that) {
    return this.type.compareTo(that.type);
}
```

note that is is possible since `Enum<E>` implements `Comparable<E>` via the natural order of the enum

so doing

```
System.out.println(list);
Collections.sort(list);
System.out.println(list);
```

will produce:

```
[Bean{type=B}, Bean{type=INVALID}, Bean{type=C}, Bean{type=A}, Bean{type=B}, Bean{type=INVALID}, Bean{type=C}, Bean{type=A}]
[Bean{type=A}, Bean{type=A}, Bean{type=B}, Bean{type=B}, Bean{type=C}, Bean{type=C}, Bean{type=INVALID}, Bean{type=INVALID}]
```

Comment: yes, adding INVALID enum value should be more sane. But, if i'm not allowed to add any new value to the enum, how to resolve this then

Answer (score 1):

I see no particular problems with CompareTo apart from its complexity scaling with growing enum.
The problem is in different thing: priorityQueue.toString does not pull items from queue, it simply prints underlying binary heap structure.

Please note, that binary heap is only partially ordered. It ensures a[i]>a[2*i] and a[2*i+1], nothing can be said in advance about ordering for a[2*i] and a[2*i+1].

This question already appeared in stackoverflow:
[PriorityQueue.toString wrong element order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27806315/priorityqueue-tostring-wrong-element-order)

Answer (score 0):

You are not accounting for all the possible combinations of `this.type` and `that.type`.  You forgot:

- `if (this.type == Type.B && that.type == Type.A)`
- `if (this.type == Type.C && that.type == Type.A)`
- `if (this.type == Type.C && that.type == Type.B)`

However, there is a much easier way.  All enum constants are Comparable.  Their natural ordering is the order in which they were declared in the source.  So you can just do:

```
if (this.type != null && that.type != null) {
    return this.type.compareTo(that.type);
}
```