# How Integer Data get Inserted in Prioroty Queue(Sequence Not able to undestand)

Tags: java, collections, priority-queue

I am learning Priority Queue of Java in Collection framework.

Currently I am on the topic called Priority Queue. I referred the following [article](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/priority-queue-class-in-java-2/) and this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1mm1I40cniQ) to learn, then I tested the code on IDE

```
int ar[] = {3, 5, 12, 9, 1};
PriorityQueue<Integer>  pq = new PriorityQueue<>();
for(int f:ar)
pq.add(f);
```

When I am printing pq iam getting [1, 3, 12, 9, 5]

How this sequence is arrange (What is the priority here?) I am not understanding, as it is not increasing order or decreasing order. please guide

Comment: The priority is just to have the topmost element the minimum number

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27806315/priorityqueue-tostring-wrong-element-order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PriorityQueue` stores the elements in the natural order unless a `Comparator` is provided while creating the queue.

```
int ar[] = {3, 5, 12, 9, 1};
PriorityQueue<Integer>  pq = new PriorityQueue<>();
for(int f:ar)
  pq.add(f);
System.out.println(pq);
```

The result is `[1, 3, 12, 9, 5]` as `toString` method of `AbstractCollection` class is called when you print the queue.

```
public String toString() {
  Iterator<E> it = iterator();
  if (! it.hasNext())
    return "[]";

  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  sb.append('[');
  for (;;) {
    E e = it.next();
    sb.append(e == this ? "(this Collection)" : e);
    if (! it.hasNext())
      return sb.append(']').toString();
    sb.append(',').append(' ');
  }
}
```

`iterator()` used here is implemented in the `PriorityQueue` class which does not return the elements in any particular order. Hence, when you print the priority queue, it prints the elements without any order.

```
/**
 * Returns an iterator over the elements in this queue. The iterator
 * does not return the elements in any particular order.
 *
 * @return an iterator over the elements in this queue
 */
public Iterator<E> iterator() {
    return new Itr();
}
```

If you want to know the order of elements stored in the queue, you have to poll elements and print them.

```
int ar[] = {3, 5, 12, 9, 1};
PriorityQueue<Integer>  pq = new PriorityQueue<>(ar.length);
for(int f:ar)
  pq.add(f);

while(!pq.isEmpty())
  System.out.println(pq.poll());
```

this will give you elements in the order they are stored.

```
1
3
5
9
12
```

Answer (score 1):

it is stored as min heap. read more about min heap

Comment: [Wikipedia article on Heaps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure))