# have a problem sorting priority queue integers

Tags: java, sorting, priority-queue

hello i wonder what's wrong with my code:
It should have an output like this:

[image]

in this problem  I need to implement different queue operations  by adding element, removing element, size of priority queue, print the queue and top element of queue

Input Format

The first line of input contains an integer T denoting the no of test cases. For each test case, the first line of input contains an integer Q denoting the no of queries followed by Q space separated queries. A query can be of the following types:

1.x (Adding x to the priority queue and print the queue)

2.(Removing the element from the top of the priority queue and printing that element )

3.(Get the element at the top of the priority queue)

4.(Get the size of the priority queue)

5.(Print the priority queue)

```
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.PriorityQueue;
import java.util.Scanner;

class Solution {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner scanner= new Scanner(System.in);
        int T=scanner.nextInt();
        int i=0;
        int Q=scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.println();
        PriorityQueue<Integer>pq=new PriorityQueue<>(new Comparator<Integer>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {
                return o2.compareTo(o1);
            }
        });
        while (i<T){
            for (int j = 0; j < Q; j++) {


                int query=scanner.nextInt();

                switch (query){
                    case 1:

                        pq.add(scanner.nextInt());
                        System.out.println(pq.toString().replace("[","").replace("]","").replace(",",""));
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        System.out.println(pq.poll());
                        break;
                    case 3:

                        System.out.println(pq.peek());
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        System.out.println(pq.size());
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        System.out.println(pq.toString().replace("[","").replace("]","").replace(",",""));
                    default:
                        break;
                }}
            i++;
        }}
}
```

but when I'm running my code it gives me  output like this:

[image]

Comment: Please, [don't post your code/error messages/expected output as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/4298200). Firstly we want to copy/paste it and secondly search engines are unable to index that information. So please make sure that any textual information is actually provided in text form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your queue printing code have some problems, try this code instead:

```
public static void printQueue(PriorityQueue<Integer> p1)
{
    PriorityQueue<Integer> p2 = new PriorityQueue<>(p1);

    while (!p2.isEmpty())
    {
        System.out.print(p2.poll() + " ");
    }

    System.out.println();
}
```

You can find the explanation here:

[PriorityQueue.toString wrong element order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27806315/priorityqueue-tostring-wrong-element-order)