# Sorting priority queue for a range of elements with higher priority and other elements with lower priority

Tags: java, sorting, comparator, priority-queue, comparable

I have an entity class with the following fields: id, orderNo. Each
entity must be stored in a java priority queue. Elements
with id between 1 - 3000 have higher priority and must be stored in
ascending order of orderNo above the elements with id > 3000. Elements
with ids > 3000 are stored in the ascending order of orderNo below the
higher priority elements (with ids 1 - 3000).

Eg:

```
(1st insertion to queue: id=4000 orderNo=1) 
(2nd insertion to queue: id=5000 orderNo=2) 
(3rd insertion to queue: id=100  orderNo=3)
(4th insertion to queue: id=50   orderNo=4)
```

**Expected sort sequence:**

```
(id=100  orderNo=3) 
(id=50   orderNo=4) 
(id=4000 orderNo=1) 
(id=5000 orderNo=2)
```

OrderEntity class:

```
public class OrderEntity implements Comparable<OrderEntity> {
    private int id;
    private int getOrderNo;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getOrderNo() {
        return getOrderNo;
    }

    public void setOrderNo(int getOrderNo) {
        this.getOrderNo = getOrderNo;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(OrderEntity arg0) {
        if ((this.getId() >= 1 && this.getId() <= 3000) && (arg0.getId() >= 1 && arg0.getId() <= 3000)) {
            if (this.getOrderNo() > arg0.getOrderNo()) {
                return 1;
            } else {
                return 0;
            }
        } else if ((this.getId() <= 3000) && (arg0.getId() > 3000)) {
            return 1;
        } else if ((this.getId() > 3000) && (arg0.getId() <= 3000)) {
            return 1;
        } else if ((this.getId() > 3000) && (arg0.getId() > 3000)) {
            if (this.getOrderNo() > arg0.getOrderNo()) {
                return 1;
            } else {
                return 0;
            }
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

OrderProcessor class:

```
public class OrderProcessor {
    private static int count;
    static Queue<OrderEntity> pq = new PriorityQueue<>();

    public String createOrder(int id) {
        OrderEntity orderEntity = new OrderEntity();
        orderEntity.setId(id);
        count = count + 1;
        orderEntity.setOrderNo(count);
        pq.add(orderEntity);

        String res = "";
        for (OrderEntity rd : pq) {
            res = res + rd.getId() + " " + rd.getOrderNo() + "\n";
        }
        return res.trim();
    }
}
```

Comment: And your question is...?

Comment: My question is that I am not able to get this sequence with the above implementation. Wanted to know where I am going wrong.

Comment: One problem is your `compareTo` method, which returns 0 (meaning equal) if the first item is not greater than the second. `compareTo` should return -1, 0, or 1, depending on whether the first item is less than, equal to, or greater than the second. Typically, you use `Integer.compare` to check that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In such cases that the natural ordering of the objects is different from your special requirement it's better not to use `Comparable` because it might have other usages in future. So, the remaining solution is using `Comparator` which suits your problem very well because your `OrderEntity` class won't have a dependency on this special compare. the following is a sample code showing the solution:

```
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.PriorityQueue;

public class OrderProcessor {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PriorityQueue<OrderEntity> q = new PriorityQueue<>(new OrderEntityComparator());
        q.add(new OrderEntity(4000, 1));
        q.add(new OrderEntity(5000, 2));
        q.add(new OrderEntity(100, 3));
        q.add(new OrderEntity(50, 4));

        while(!q.isEmpty())
            System.out.println(q.poll());
    }

    public static class OrderEntityComparator implements Comparator<OrderEntity> {

        @Override
        public int compare(OrderEntity o1, OrderEntity o2) {
            if(o1.getId() <= 3000 && o2.getId() <= 3000)
                return Integer.compare(o1.getOrderNo(), o2.getOrderNo());
            if(o1.getId() > 3000 && o2.getId() > 3000)
                return Integer.compare(o1.getOrderNo(), o2.getOrderNo());
            if(o1.getId() <= 3000 && o2.getId() > 3000)
                return -1;
            return 1;
        }
    }

    public static class OrderEntity {
        private int id;
        private int orderNo;

        public OrderEntity(int id, int orderNo) {
            this.id = id;
            this.orderNo = orderNo;
        }

        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public int getOrderNo() {
            return orderNo;
        }

        public void setOrderNo(int orderNo) {
            this.orderNo = orderNo;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "OrderEntity{" +
                    "id=" + id +
                    ", orderNo=" + orderNo +
                    '}';
        }
    }
}
```

edited:

In case you don't want to remove elements by calling `poll` method, you have to sort your elements in an array or a List, something like this:

```
    OrderEntity[] a = new OrderEntity[q.size()];
    q.toArray(a);
    Arrays.sort(a, new OrderEntityComparator());

    for(OrderEntity entity : a)
        System.out.println(entity);
```

In fact, in such case you don't need to use a `PriorityQueue` and a simple sort on a List or an array will do the job.

Comment: Not working. Try with the following input: (100,1) (200,2) (4000,3) (300,4). Expected output: (100,1) (200,2) (300,4) (4000,3). Actual Output: (100,1) (200,2) (4000,3) (300,4)

Comment: @AshwinShirva What your expected output is? My output is: (100,1) (200,2) (300,4) (4000,3)

Comment: @AshwinShirva I ran the code and the output was the same as you expected. Would you please check my code?

Comment: @MehdiJavan I accepted your proposed edit of the question with a minor edit of my own :)

Comment: It works, with poll() inside while loop as you mentioned. A quick question, is there a way to traverse priority queue elements in order without using poll()? Because I donot want to modify the original queue. I just want to retrieve the values(in order).

Comment: @AshwinShirva PriorityQueue doesn't what you want as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8129159/5613292 . Though, I added some code to my answer to fulfill your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using Java 8 that doesn't need any complicated comparator implementation. I ran it against both the examples you provided. The trick is to realize that there are 2 groups of ids, those <= 3000, and those above. If you can somehow normalize the numbers in these 2 groups, then you can simply use natural ordering of the normalized ids followed by natural ordering by order number.

```
public class Main {
    private static Comparator<OrderEntity> orderEntityComparator =
        Comparator.<OrderEntity, Integer>comparing(OrderEntity::getId,
                comparingInt(id -> id / 3000)
        )
                .thenComparingInt(OrderEntity::getOrderNo);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PriorityQueue<OrderEntity> queue = new PriorityQueue<>(orderEntityComparator);
        queue.add(new OrderEntity(4000, 1));
        queue.add(new OrderEntity(5000, 2));
        queue.add(new OrderEntity(100, 3));
        queue.add(new OrderEntity(50, 4));

        // 100, 50, 4000, 5000

        queue.clear();

        queue.add(new OrderEntity(100, 1));
        queue.add(new OrderEntity(200, 2));
        queue.add(new OrderEntity(4000, 3));
        queue.add(new OrderEntity(300, 4));

        while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println(queue.poll());
        }
        // 100, 200, 300, 4000
    }

    static class OrderEntity {
        private int id;
        private int orderNo;

        public OrderEntity(int id, int orderNo) {
            this.id = id;
            this.orderNo = orderNo;
        }

        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public int getOrderNo() {
            return orderNo;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return String.format("(id=%d, orderNo=%d)", id, orderNo);
        }
    }
}
```