# How to insert an Object into a LinkedList depending on priority

Tags: java, sorting, linked-list

I have an Object with a "priority" that is an int ranging from 1-3, increasing meaning higher priority of course.

I have a Linked list that has objects in a sort of Queue. Basically what I want to do is loop through the LinkedList, and compare the new Object to the Objects already in the list, and if the Object reaches an Object where It has a higher int priority than the next Object, I want it inserted before the Object with the lower priority.

If the case is where the Object has the same priority as other Objects, I want it inserted behind the Objects with the same priority as it. If the Object is unable to find another Object with lower priority than it, I simply want it Inserted at the end.

This is what I currently have

```
User s;
ListIterator <User> queue = getList().listIterator();
if (queue.hasNext()) {
    User next;
    while (queue.hasNext()) {
        next = queue.next();
        if (queue.hasNext() && next.getId() < s.getId()) {
            queue.add(next);
            queue.set(s);
        } else {
            queue.add(next);
        }
    }
}else {
  queue.add(s);
}
```

Comment: Have you investigated `java.util.PriorityQueue`?

Comment: @JimGarrison I have never seen that before, that seems perfect!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `java.util.PriorityQueue` instead.

To satisfy your requirement that equal-priority entries must be removed in order of insertion you will need to provide a custom comparator based on priority and time-stamp.  If you cannot modify the entry objects to include a timestamp, this will require creating a wrapper to hold the priority, timestamp and reference to the entry.  However, it will ensure that later entries with identical priorities come later in removal order.

Also pay attention to the fact that the iterator for a `PriorityQueue` returns entries in random order and does NOT iterate in priority order.  Only removal is guaranteed to return entries in priority order.  (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/8129239/18157 for an explanation of why)

Comment: Does the pol method bring the Object with the highest priority?

Comment: Yes.  Study the Javadoc, the class is well documented.  The "head" of the queue is always guaranteed to be the entry with the "highest" priority.

Comment: One last question and I promise I'll leave you alone haha. How could I go about getting an Objects position (index) in the queue? Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: Nevermind, seems I can't do that. Looks like I'll just have to use a list.