# Sort items in queue

Tags: java, priority-queue

I have a class Person which has a field - `age`. Objects from this class are put in a queue:

```
ArrayDeque<Person> queue = new ArrayDeque<Person>();
```

I would like to sort items in a queue in a way that a Person with the biggest value of `age` property becomes the first in a queue. I tried to use `priorityQueue` but don't know how to copy values from a normal queue to a priority one and at the same time use a comparator to sort. How do I make it work?

```
Comparator<Person> sorter = Comparator.comparing(Person::getAge);

PriorityQueue<Person> priorityQueue = new PriorityQueue<Person>(queue, sorter);
(this is obviously invalid, is there a workaround so as to copy the queue and have a comparator at the same time?)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`PriorityQueue(Comparator<? super E> comparator)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html#PriorityQueue-java.util.Comparator-) constructor, then call [`addAll(Collection<? extends E> c)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/AbstractQueue.html#addAll-java.util.Collection-).

Since you said *"**biggest value** of age property becomes the **first**"*, you need to reverse the [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) by calling [`reversed()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#reversed--).

Since `getAge()` likely returns an `int`, you should use [`comparingInt(ToIntFunction<? super T> keyExtractor)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#comparingInt-java.util.function.ToIntFunction-).

```
Comparator<Person> sorter = Comparator.comparingInt(Person::getAge).reversed();

PriorityQueue<Person> priorityQueue = new PriorityQueue<>(sorter);
priorityQueue.addAll(queue);
```

Comment: After using this implementation for some time, I run into problems that it compares only first two objects in a queue, the rest is left untouched.

Comment: @kabugh I doubt you're right about that. However, remember that you cannot see the order by iterating a [`PriorityQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html): *The `Iterator` provided in method `iterator()` is not guaranteed to traverse the elements of the priority queue in any particular order. If you need ordered traversal, consider using `Arrays.sort(pq.toArray())`.* --- See e.g. [How to iterate over a PriorityQueue?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8129122/5221149)